# Mapping elements using multi-line functions

Tags: python, lambda

Consider following example in JavaScript:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3]

var y = x
          .map(i => i * 2)
          .map(i => i * i)
```

If I would like to call some function that does some external-state manipulation, like logging or publishing message to a topic I would simply use the brackets to get multi-line lambda:

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3]

var y = x
          .map(i => i * 2)
          .map(i => {
            console.log("arg received ": + i)
            return i * i
          })
```

As far as I know, such a trivial thing is impossible to do in Python because of single line lambdas and we have to use named functions which sucks because any code reader or code reviewer have to jump between function definition and function usage, even though the function is used only once.

Is there any industry standard for solving such a trivial issue?

Comment: Why not just define the function nested inside whatever function you'd use it in? the same way you'd do it in javascript. Or perhaps revert to a for loop

Comment: Because of jumping between definition and usage, even though it's used only once.

Comment: Python doesn't have variable declarations, so it's unclear what the purpose of  `var x` `var y` are — it's not Python.

Comment: The first line of my question states that the example are in JavaScript.

Comment: @martineau - Thats javascript code, I believe the OP is asking how to define a temporary function in python thats sole purpose is to be used as a single use mapping func

Comment: Tomasz: Sorry, missed that — just saw the "python" tag.

Comment: Specifically for logging or other "void" functions, you could use `or`: `map(lambda x: print(x) or x, collection)`. Whether that's good style is a different question.

Comment: @tobias_k More robust (but still far from good style) is `map(lambda x: (print(x), x)[1], collection)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for logging or other "void" functions, you could use `or`:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x*x, map(lambda x: print(x) or x, map(lambda x: x*2, lst))))
2
4
6
[4, 16, 36]
```

Here, `a or b` is equivalent to `a if a else b`, and since `print(x)` evaluates to `None`, which is not "truthy", the "else" part is returned after the `print` is executed.

Also works as a (nested) list comprehension/generator:

```
>>> [print(x) or x*x for x in (x*2 for x in lst)]
2
4
6
[4, 16, 36]
```

Whether that's good style is a different question, though.

Alternatively, and probably a bit cleaner, define a log/peek/debug function that logs the value and then returns it, to be put anywhere in your map/list-comp chain:

```
>>> def peek(x, f=print):
...     f(x)
...     return x
...
>>> [x*x for x in map(peek, (x*2 for x in lst))]
2
4
6
[4, 16, 36]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't really have this concept, the best you can do is just to define an inner function right above where you'd use it

```
def my_func(i):
    return i * i
y = map(my_func, map(lambda i: i * i, x))
```